# fadeTo transparency issue in IE 8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, transparency, fadeto

I'm having an issue with getting transparency to work in IE8 inconjunction with fadeTo. Instead of fading in and out with transparency maintained on my background image (PNG), there is a nasty black border where the transparency would otherwise be.

I've searched high and low and while there are a tonne of what seems to be good answers here on SO, I am unable to find one that works for me and I am at a loss as to why.

Here is my code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        InOut($('#bubblewrap li:first'));

        function InOut(elem) {
            elem.delay().fadeTo(1500, 1).delay(700).fadeTo(1500, 0, function() {
                if (elem.next().length > 0) {
                    InOut($(this).next());
                }
                else {
                    InOut($(this).siblings(':first'));
                }

            });
        }

        $('#bubblewrap li').mouseover(function() {
            $(this).siblings().add(this).stop(true, false).css("opacity", 0);
            $(this).show().css("opacity", 1);
        });
        $('#bubblewrap li').mouseout(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":visible") == true) {
                InOut($(this));
            }
        });
    });
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to work in some of the common solutions found on SO into my code? Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure... You mean while the element containing the background image should fade and the image with it, the background image does not show at all, and the element has a black border?

Comment: @kontur Thanks for your reply, it's probably best you view the source link located [HERE](http://www.wordpresstemplatecustomization.com/mtc/). The `<li>` contains a .png background image that should fadeTo (in & out). While this works in other browsers, I get no love in IE8.

Comment: Okay, I see, the semitransparent parts of the png are shown with a black background behind them. See nothing like it before. :(

Answer (score 1):

IE8 (as olders IE) can't handle opacity on semitransparent (ie png) elements. This is exactly what you see there. Normally setting background color (thus the element doesn't have semitransparent pixels), along with the image helps.

In you case you can consider a) not fading but showing only for IE<9 b) using part of jpg image as background, and put png on it (requires an extra element) c) recreate the effect with css3 border radius and box shadow and let css3pie deal with it. But it may not go well with animations - haven't tried this.